# Ektron Flash Widget Crashes

Tags: flash, ektron

I am new to Ektron. The project that the team (that I just joined) has been working on uses Page Builder with Ektron. But I do not think this really has anything to do with the problems we have with the Flash Widget. But it might. Suddenly, without any one altering any code, the flash widget is showing this error message. Can anyone explain why? [image: http://i67.photobucket.com/albums/h292/Athono/Adobe/flashwidget_zpsdb07e04c.png]

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked to see if your license keys have expired?

Answer (score 0):

If you could post some source code that would be helpful.

From just this information I would investigate:

1. Does you company have a valid account with the company providing the quiz.
2. If they don't get valid account have the powers that be update their account.
3. If they do have a valid account check to see that you are passing the right credentials to the company providing the quiz. Typically the quiz provider will have a FAQ. Check their source code example if they have one and compare it to the HTML that Ektron is generating. You can always enlist the quiz providers help because they are a service company and should be happy to help.